# Gatsby Source API Server Converting Name of Property and not allowing GraphQL Query

Tags: graphql, gatsby

The Gatsby Source API Server is working pretty well. With this in my gatsby-config:

```
    {
        resolve: 'gatsby-source-apiserver',
        options: {
            typePrefix: 'community_education__',
            url: `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DLAVN3q758sPohCFeZlVSVRZKXzEser1SIsQnH2mvrw/ogwtdyp/public/basic?hl=en_US&alt=json`,
            method: 'get',
            name: `classes`,
            entityLevel: `feed.entry`,
            schemaType: classType,
            localSave: true,
            path: `${__dirname}/api/`,
            verboseOutput: true,
        }
    }
```

It is correctly pulling down the data that I want. The problem is that the API I am using (google) brings back properties like:

```
{
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "$t": "Computer Coding for Kids"
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "text",
      "$t": "district: Hopkins, days: Mon - Thurs, startdate: 6/11/2018, enddate: 6/14/2018, time: 9am - Noon, grades: 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th Grades, description: Learn how to code through playing games and having fun! We'll learn the fundamentals of loops, if statements, and variables as we learn the blockly and python computer languages!  Please come with internet navigation skills (basic typing and mouse control) and a passion to work hard and have fun!, link: https://hopkins.ce.eleyo.com/course/6064/youth-summer-2018/computer-coding-for-kids"
    }
  }
```

When I go to make a GraphQL query, the properties available are `type` and `alternative__t` which would actually be ok, except that `alternative__t` is always returning `null`.

This query:

```
{
  allCommunityEducationClasses {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        title {
          type
          alternative__t
        }
        content {
          type
          alternative__t
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns this result:

```
    {
      "node": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "alternative__t": null
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "alternative__t": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "alternative__t": null
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "alternative__t": null
        }
      }
    },
```

I know that the problem is the `$t`, and if it was my own API and I could change the response name property, I would, but this is the google API. Can I rename the property somehow? Is there a way to use an escape character to query for `$t`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the library is checking for special characters, but not for `$`. I was able to fix it in my code by changing the `.replace` to `.replace(/-|__|:|\$|\.|\s/g, '_');` in `normalize.js` and this fixed my issue.

I made a Pull Request as well. https://github.com/thinhle-agilityio/gatsby-source-apiserver/pull/1